# Use a common code for multiple NODES with one variable value change [python]

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to control multiple differential drive robots.

I wrote a NODE in python which is able to control the robot i.e. publishes velocity and steering of robot using some sensor feedback.

Now I am copying the same code again and again with different names eg **controller1.py** **controller2.py** etc
Inside the codes the change is just one variable (name='bot_0' or 'bot_1' or 'bot_2' and so on).

Thus, I was thinking if there is some way in which I can **replicate** the node from roslaunch and pass one argument. This will make code more scalable and manageable.

Kindly provide your inputs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256620/use-a-common-code-for-multiple-nodes-with-one-variable-value-change-%5Bpython%5D/) by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use ROS parameters to change the configuration values of your nodes at run time; have a look at the [rospy parameters tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters) for how to retrieve parameters. The [roslaunch XML reference](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) explains the tags that are available in roslaunch.

If you use a private parameter to configure your node, your launch file would look something like:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="my_controller_package" type="controller.py" name="controller1">
    <param name="name" value="bot_1"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="my_controller_package" type="controller.py" name="controller2">
    <param name="name" value="bot_2"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Assuming that your node is called `controller.py` in a package named `my_controller_package`; this sets the private parameter `name` for each node, which you can retrieve in rospy with `rospy.get_param("~name")`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-26**:
The ability to reuse nodes and run multiple instances simultaneously with different configurations via parameters is one of ROS's biggest strengths. This answer is an excellent example of this.